# Redirect exclusion rule in .htaccess does not work

Tags: redirection, .htaccess, uri

I have a rule in my .htaccess to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS,
and I'm trying to exclude some specific URL from redirect, so I added the negation exclusion rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_url
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But this doesn't work, http://example.com/my_url redirects to front page example.com. Is it interfering with some other rules? All are standard Drupal core .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's interference with other Drupal rewrite rules. If you have clean URLs enabled, you're rewriting each request as an argument to index.php. Add an additional check to exclude this other rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've also tryied to add this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php whith no luck, i also tryed to comment all this: RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] still no reaction/

Comment: As a general rule for testing redirects, you want to turn off all browser caching. Browsers cache HTTP 301/302 responses and it can confuse the state of your redirect testing.

Comment: See [How long is a 302 redirect saved in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212839/how-long-is-a-302-redirect-saved-in-browser) & [How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)